# package org.eclipse.swt does not exist

Tags: maven, jenkins, package, swt, rcp

I am getting compilation error while running a project in Jenkins. The following are few of those similar errors:

```
cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable SWT

package org.eclipse.swt does not exist
and
package org.eclipse.swt.widgets does not exist
```

I am new to rcp. Not sure how to handle this. I am using Maven 3.3.9 and JDK 1.8.

Comment: Can you explain why they *should* be found in this context?

Comment: You need to give us a lot more details about how you are trying to build your RCP. Note that maven + tycho is the currently recommended build method.